# A construction for the free $\omega$-category generated by a globular set

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

The forgetful functor from strict $\omega$-categories to globular sets has a left adjoint. Where can one find an explicit construction for this free functor?

Comment: See Tom Leinster's book, chapter 8: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305049.pdf.